# Why does Kaido want to kill Whitebeard?

Tags: one-piece

According to Wikia, [Kaido's article](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido#Yonko):

> [...] Kaido and Edward Newgate were not allies, yet would not, under normal circumstances, provoke each other. However, Kaido saw the opportunity to take down his rival prior to the impending Battle of Marineford, and did not hesitate to take advantage to attempt so.

I don't know why Kaido wants to kill Whitebeard at first place. Are there any evidences from the series that suggest so?

Answer (score 2):

Pirates are pirates. If they see a chance, they will take it. Also Kaido could have gained much with Whitebeard's death.

According to [the Wikia article about the Yonkou](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yonko) (sorry, I couldn't find the chapter where they actually say this):

> [...] the Yonko stuck in a deadlock situation [...]

Ideally Whitebeard's death would have given Kaido the advantage he needed to advance in the New World and eventually become the Pirate King. He just didn't expect Shanks to help out Whitebeard, or Blackbeard to be so swift taking his place and becoming a Yonkou maintaining their deadlock.

Comment: Ideally, the answer should cite which chapter, since you are currently using secondary source and even the same source as the question.

Comment: Still working on it. But all I could find is a discussion between some random people who also want to find which chapter was this.

Comment: At the end of that paragraph the wiki refers to chapter 233, where the five elder stars mention how the world is stable now (the deadlock I presume) and if something were to happen to Shanks (or any other yonkou), the world would plunge into chaos and things will be tough.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I checked that chapter (actually any chapter that I know where somebody was talking about the Yonko) but I do remember myself somebody somewhere actually using the phrase "deadlock" or "stalemate" in the manga. I just can't find it. Maybe I'm getting old. Maybe I start to imagine things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally:

> From what is shown, Kaido is a merciless and confident warrior who never lets an opportunity slip by, as evidenced by his plan to attack Whitebeard during the latter's attempt to save Portgas D. Ace from execution.
>
> He is also **pitiless and not open to negotiations and excuses**, which makes it seemingly unwise to provoke or underestimate him. This is enforced dramatically when Donquixote Doflamingo, a Shichibukai and World Noble known for his fearless and confident attitude...

So he's very rash like Ruffy and doesn't think very much, if he sees an opportunity to get a step closer to the title "Pirate King", he takes it.

*You find more information about him on http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kaido*